Obtaining Permission to Open Local Disk D
while I was checking the permissions of users, I accidentally put a tick on deny for read and write for local disk D.

When I try to go to the security tab of properties again, it says you need to have permission to read in order to view the properties of the object. Press advanced to continue.

Then, this window opens. It says click continue to try this operation with administrator permissions.

I click continue, it is stubborn and says you do not have the right to see the security properties even if you are an administrator user. Press change above to try to get permission to change the owner having the permission to read.

Finally, I encountered this screen. 5 I seriously have no idea what this tab is about.


As an administrator, change, take ownership, and then change the permissions.  You shouldn't actually have to take ownership if Administrator users still have access. Your screenshots are not in English, so I can't provide any additional information.

I tried to translate as much as possible. typing "Administrators" and "Users" worked. Then, I was able to change the permissions. Thank you for your help
